# Is it possible to post login form to an external web app and also redirect to that app's front page?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, security

I have a web application that when user click on the a link it will generate security information and log on to an external application if the security information is authenticated.

At this point from security concern I don't want to expose the URL and request information on the web page, so instead I am seeking solutions to handle the process behind the scene

I know [`Apache Components`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java) can easily send post request within POJO, `jersey client` can do as well through web service. However the requirement here is also including to let browser automatically redirect to the 3rd app's front page if the login process succeeded.

My question is what could be the proper solution to handle the login process and go to the external application from web as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have:

1. publicapp.com
2. secretapp.com

Set up an API in publicapp.com to POST the initial request to itself. When the user submits the initial login form it goes to say publicapp.com/login. This endpoint will pre-process the information then send a server to server request to secretapp.com/login.

If secretapp.com/login accepts the information it responds to publicapp.com with a success and publicapp.com redirects the client to secretapp.com/home, with a short term auth token encoded in a JWT. secretapp.com, swaps the short term token for a full auth token.

In the above scenario, the actual login endpoint is never made public. secretapp.com should also have IP whitelisting to only accepts login attempts from publicapp.com. You can also do a lot of filtering on publicapp.com to eliminate malicious requests without bothering secretapp.com.

Comment: Thanks. `...and publicapp.com redirects the client to secretapp.com/home.` in this case how to protect the redirect to `secretapp.com` without carrying further authentication information for the secretapp? Seems only the login for publicapp.com is protected by if the redirection exposed then secretapp also compromised.

Comment: @Dreamer I adde more detail that hopefully covers what you want.